# DNS setup over RRAS, Can't join Domain Controller

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, domain-name, rras

I currently have 1 domain controller in one of our premises. I have another server 2008 r2 which I have installed RRAS on and have setup 2 direct dials on either end and they have connected fine.

Server1 - IP 192.168.1.2
Server2 - IP 192.168.0.200

On Server1 and Server2 I have DNS setup.

If I navigate to \\192.168.1.2 from Server2 I can see shares on Server1 however if I try to ping Server1 from Server2 I get a "Request Timed Out"?

When I run DCpromo to try and join Server2 to the domain I get the error:

*The following error occurred when DNS was queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate an Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for domain "DOMAINHIDDEN.Local":

The error was: "DNS name does not exist."
(error code 0x0000232B RCODE_NAME_ERROR)

The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.DOMAINHIDDEN.Local
Common causes of this error include the following:

The DNS SRV records required to locate a AD DC for the domain are not registered in DNS. These records are registered with a DNS server automatically when a AD DC is added to a domain. They are updated by the AD DC at set intervals. This computer is configured to use DNS servers with the following IP addresses:

127.0.0.1

192.168.1.2

One or more of the following zones do not include delegation to its child zone:

DOMAINHIDDEN.Local
local
. (the root zone)*

My question is how do I join Server2 over RRAS to Server1? Do I need to do anything with DNS settings within IPv4 of RRAS?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regardless if the connection is via RRAS, is name resolution working? Did you open firewall on either server for ping and essential TCP ports to work?

Comment: Name resolution is working and I currently have both firewalls down on routers and both servers

Comment: If this is the server that not yet in domain, how can name resolution works if you set it to use itself as DNS? The error message said that you are using 127.0.0.1 as first DNS server - so unless 2.200 is a DNS server itself, I don't see how name resolution is going to work. Remove 127.0.0.1 from your TCP/IP stack/DNS servers.